# ScrollViewer and TextBlock wrapping

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have the following layout (simplified):

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="400" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <!-- Code for Column=0 -->

  <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid x:Name="layoutGrid">

      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <Grid.ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="400" />
        <Grid.ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>


      <!-- Code for Row=0 and Row=1 -->

      <GroupBox Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row=2>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
      </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

- First column should occupy space as mush as it needs (sometimes it can be 100 pixels, sometimes 500).
- Second column Should stretch to available space, but no more than 400 pixels (gets ugly).
- Third column should occupy space as much as it needs (sometimes it can be 200 pixels, sometimes 400).
- If, in some rare cases, layoutGrid needs space more than available on the screen, horizontal scrollbar should be visible.
- GroupBox should always have the total width of all three columns (it should spread as much as their width is in total). And in that space, text box should wrap. GroupBox should not stretch to whole space available on screen.

How can I achieve this in xaml? It seems that as soon as ScrollViewer is inserted, TextBlock does not wrap any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just give the `TextBlock` a `MaxWidth` which is the `ActualWidth` of either the `GroupBox` or in your case even the `layoutGrid` (as your `GroupBox` has the same width). This would force the `TextBlock` to have to wrap when it's `Width` exceeds that dimension and thereby giving you your requirement.

So something like:

```
<GroupBox x:Name="grpBox"
          Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
  <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=grpBox,
                                Path=ActualWidth}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Text="{Binding ...}"
              TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</GroupBox>
```

or

```
<TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=layoutGrid,
                              Path=ActualWidth}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="{Binding ...}"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Comment: Hi Viv, thanks for the tip. IT cannot be done on the GroupBox, or LayoutGrid, since those are the parent elements of the TextBlock, and they will set their width as much as their chilren request (in our case one of the children is TextBlock). But advice can be safely applied if we remove GroupBox outside the layoutGrid and place it right below, then their sizes do not directly influence each other, so your tip can be applied.

Comment: Works almost, however down-sizing doesn't shrink the `ActualWidth`. Therefore, only upsizing is possible. Is there any solution to that?

Answer (score 4):

I have created a control wrapper [IgnoreWidthControl](https://gist.github.com/xmedeko/2ccba5649bbfb4bf5d1c5183910e0378) for this purpose:

```
public class IgnoreWidthControl : ContentControl
{
    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        if (sizeInfo.WidthChanged)
            InvalidateMeasure();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        constraint.Width = ActualWidth;
        Size size = new Size();
        UIElement child = GetFirstVisualChild();
        if (child != null)
        {
            child.Measure(constraint);
            size.Height = child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }

        return size;
    }

    private UIElement GetFirstVisualChild()
    {
        if (this.VisualChildrenCount <= 0)
            return null;
        return this.GetVisualChild(0) as UIElement;
    }
}
```

And the example use:

```
<myc:IgnoreWidthControl>
    <TextBlock Text="Very long text which has to be wrapped. Yeah, it must be wrapped." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</myc:IgnoreWidthControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had TextBlocks data bound in an `<ItemsControl>` and wanted them to stack vertically like a chatroom. The longer TextBlocks weren't wrapping.

I changed the `<ScrollViewer>` `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` from `Hidden` to `Disabled`. This caused TextBlocks to wrap across lines even when resizing:

```
        <ScrollViewer 
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                      <ItemsControl 
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                         Height="Auto" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think about your situation logically, then you'll understand that of course a `TextBlock` without its `Width` property set will not wrap when put inside a `ScrollViewer`. A `TextBlock` can only wrap its text if it is told when to start wrapping... by 'when', I really mean 'where'. It needs to be told, 'at 150 pixels from the left, start wrapping the text content'.

Now we can tell it to do that like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some random long text string that is longer than 150 pixels long" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" />
```

Or like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some random long text string that is longer than 150 pixels long" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="150" />
```

Or like this:

```
<Grid Width="150">
    <TextBlock Text="Some random long text string that is longer than 150 pixels long" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
```

Or like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Some random long text string that is longer than 
        150 pixels long" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
```

However, if you remove the `Width` restriction, then the `TextBlock` will never know when it should start wrapping the `Text`. By putting your `TextBlock` into a `ScrollViewer`, you are telling it that it has all the space that it could possibly want and therefore, without setting a `Width` restriction on it, it will never wrap.

Comment: Everything you said I already knew. But as i said I cannot have fixed width or TextBlock. However, it will wrap, if I take the approach given by Viv. All I had to do is make layoutGrid not to be parent of the TextBlock. This way we can set TextBlock width to the width of the layoutGrid.